# MATLAB: Output a fixed-length vector from a random-length vector?

Tags: matlab

Say I have some randomly-length vector:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 91 1 3 2 4 2 7 6 9 12 313 32 57 327 2 13]

b = [1 9 3 8 5 6 7 8 9 91 1 3 2 4 2 7 6 9 12 313 32 57 327 2 13 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I want to output a vector of length 10, with evenly spaced element (including the first and last element). I know I have to use interpolation if the original vector is not of length with multiples of 10. How can i do it?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @rahnema1 expected output is a vector of length 10, but includes the start and end points. For a, it outputs `a1 = [1 . . . . . . . . 13]` .For b, it outputs `b1 = [1 . . . . . . . . 0]`

Comment: Please exactly include the expected output.I can not understand anything from `[1....13]`

Comment: Do you want to use interpolation between the values or do you want to select evenly spaced values from the original array?

Comment: @Naveh yes if it is an array of length of multiples of 10 i want evenly spaced values from the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to use interpolation to produce a vector of 10 elements from any input vector. The following code should work.

```
b = [1 9 3 8 5 6 7 8 9 91 1 3 2 4 2 7 6 9 12 313 32 57 327 2 13 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
interp1(linspace(1,10,length(b)),b,1:10)
```

Output:

```
ans =

    1.0000    5.3333    8.7778    2.3333    6.4444  188.1111    5.6667    1.0000         0         00         0
```

Basically, you define the `b` values to be defined over the range of 1 to 10 and then resample on the 10 element vector `1:10`. If they need to be integers instead of doubles you can use `round`.

```
b = [1 9 3 8 5 6 7 8 9 91 1 3 2 4 2 7 6 9 12 313 32 57 327 2 13 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
round(interp1(linspace(1,10,length(b)),b,1:10))
```

Output:

```
ans =

     1     5     9     2     6   188     6     1     0     0
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Glad to help. So did it just help or did it actually answer your question?

Comment: i think it answers. but i have to confirm.

Comment: @kyle Please accept an answer if it solves your problem. It seems that you have asked a lot of question without accepting the answer, although there is an (upvoted) answer. If the answer isn't correct, please comment why it isn't what you are looking for.